# C# - How can I modify a struct given by a getter?

Tags: c#, getter

I'm quite new to C# and I'm still figuring things out.
My problem is that I've got a class like this:

```
class Sprite {
    private Vector3 _position;

    public Vector3 Position {
        get { return _position; }
        set { _position = value;
              HandleEvent(); }
    }

    public Sprite() {
        _position = new Vector3();
    }
}
```

With a Vector3 object and a get/set block.
Here is a simplified version of the Vector3 struct:

```
struct Vector3 {
    float X, Y, Z;
}
```

Now my problem is that if I do this:

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.Position.X += 4.0F;
```

It gives me an error because Position is not a variable but given to me by a getter. But I don't want to make _position public, because I want to handle an event when the variable is changed.

(In Java this works perfectly, that's why I'm confused :/)

Could you give me a hint what I'm doing wrong or what you would do differently?

**Edit:**

Yes, Vector3 is a struct and not a class. Sorry for the confusion, but I'm pretty new to C#.

Comment: Can you post the error message please? This should work.

Comment: Are you sure Vector3 is a class and not a struct?

Comment: Don't see anything wrong in the posted code. There must be something else which you haven't posted.

Comment: Could you show us the code for the Vector3 class? Vector3 classes are typically designed as an immutable type with read only properties for parallelism/thread safety. I doubt the issue is with the Position property, as that's not what you're trying to set.

Comment: You need to do it like this: `var temp = sprite.Position; temp.X = 4.0F; sprite.Position = temp;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (In Java this works perfectly, that's why I'm confused :/)

Java does not have what C# calls `struct`.

In C#, `struct` creates a [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx). When you return a value type from a property getter, you don't return a reference to an already existing object somewhere, you return a brand new copy of the value. And because of that, it does not make sense to modify that copy of the value: no one would see the modification.

In Java, you would use `class` for this. In C#, you can do the same. That creates a reference type. When you return a reference type from a property getter, you don't return a copy of all of the object's fields, you just return a reference to the same object. Here, modifications do make sense. You have multiple references to the same object, and the modifications are still visible through any of the other references.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That definetely helps me out :)

Answer (score 2):

Because `Vector3` is a struct, it gets copied around implicitly. For example, the following code creates *two* vectors, instead of one:

```
Vector3 tmp1 = new Vector3();
Vector3 tmp2 = tmp1;
```

This can be confusing if you're mostly used to classes, where an instance is not copied and not created unless you explicitly say so (using `new`, for example).

Combine the above with the fact that C# properties are syntactic sugar for methods, and you'll have your answer. This:

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.Position.X += 4.0F;
```

Is seen like this:

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.get_Position().X += 4.0F;
```

Which would be executed like this:

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
Vector3 tmp1 = sprite.get_Position();
tmp1.X += 4.0F;
```

Notice that `tmp1` is a brand new `Vector3`. It's unrelated to `sprite.Position` in every way, except for the fact that they contained equal coordinates at some point.

Changing that temporary `Vector3` won't have an effect on the `Vector3` returned by the property. The C# compiler is aware of this unfortunate pattern and refuses to compile it because it's almost certainly not what you want.

To work around this, you can try taking the position explicitly, like above, and then explicitly put it back:

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
Vector3 tmp1 = sprite.Position;
tmp1.X += 4.0F;
sprite.Position = tmp1;
```

In general, you should avoid mutable structs for reasons like this.

---

Java doesn't have this problem because it doesn't have structs at all.

Answer (score 1):

It *should* work fine. This sample compiles:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Sprite
    {
        private Vector3 _position;

        public Vector3 Position
        {
            get { return _position; }
            set
            {
                _position = value;
                // HandleEvent();
            }
        }

        public Sprite()
        {
            _position = new Vector3();
        }
    }

    class Vector3
    {
        public float X, Y, Z;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Sprite sprite = new Sprite();

            sprite.Position.X += 4.0F;
        }
    }
}
```

As your vector seems to be a struct, because a struct is a value-type (which means your getter that is called will return a *copy* of your position) you cannot operate on what your getter returns. You will need to make a new Vector and assign that one as a whole. Please note that this seems to be an *optimization* somebody made for you. If the Vector object definition belongs to you, just make it a class so it works like you are used to from Java.

If you *want* this to be a struct, you will have to create a new one and assign it:

```
            sprite.Position = new Vector 
                              {
                                  X = sprite.Position.X + 4.0F,
                                  Y = sprite.Position.Y,
                                  Z = sprite.Position.Z
                              };
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I edited the question. I'm quite new to C# so sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
        Vector3 v = sprite.Position;
        v.X += 0.4F;
        sprite.Position = v;
```

Cause of Error:

The problem is that `sprite.Position` returns a struct, so when you access it, it creates a copy of it due to the value semantics. += attempts to modify that value, but it'll be modifying a temporary copy - not the actual struct stored in your `sprite`.

You have to take the value from reading the Position and put it into a local variable, change that local variable, and then assign the local variable back into Position.

Comment: Thanks for the example.